# Large SQL dynamic query crash the system

Tags: mysql, oracle

We have one query similar like below with dynamic value.

```
Select * from table where dynamic value
```

So here in where part dynamic valu actullay depend on user's some value ok so lets say if user is associate with one company then query would be

`Select * from table where company is xyz and id is 123` but now lets say if hypothetically if user is associate with million company then  query would be

```
Select * from where company is 1 and id is 1 or ... company is n and id is n
```

Here n is number of company value. Here this query obviousally will take time to execute.
Is there any way we can optimize this so system won't crash. May be there are some other approach on design wise but right now we are looking for to optimize query option.

EDIT:

variable name is company and id and it wont change but their value will come dynamically. so basically if user has 1000 company then for loop will run 1000 times and the value will add each time to company and id in where condition
Here just an ex.

```
StringBuilder sql = "select * from table where ";
StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer();
for(int i=0;i<user.company.size;i++){
   query+="(company is" + user.company[i]+"AND id is" + user.id[i]+") OR";
}
sql.append(query)
```

Comment: does "dynamic value" mean variable? Which DMBS are using - you have tagged mysql AND oracle. Does this problem happen in both? Can you add the actual queries you are using (company is 1 is not valid sql) As a guess, it sounds like you should index on (Id,Company) or (Company,Id)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` condition in both Oracle and MySQL.

```
select * from where company IN (1, ..., n) and id in (1, ..., n);
```

All is left for you is how to generate the content inside `IN`.

Answer (score 0):

The best course depends on what you expect the number 'n' to be: if most of the times it is high, then you better create a temp table, put these values in it, and join with the data table. Even for small values of 'n', this should be ok. This also has the side benefit that your query will always be the same.